# Why would you create a class with one single member which is an operator()?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have tried to find out -out there- a good technical reason for defining a class which contains only one member and this member happens to be a `operator()`.

I stumbled upon someone who -for whatever the reason- created a namespace containing a couple of classes, but each class contains only one `operator()` as a member.

It is clear to me that these classes might then be used as if they were methods (very likely), but why is this a good technical approach (I assume there is a good one), rather than simply defining a set of different methods within a singleton class which in this particular case would belong to the namespace I mentioned lines above.

The namespace looks something like:

```
namespace myNamespace {
   class ClassA {
   public:
      void operator()();
   };

   class ClassB {
   public:
      int operator()(arg1, arg2);
   };

   ...
}
```

Is this simply a matter of personal taste/style or is this the expression of advance/sophisticated design?
I assume this design encompass some wise knowledge that I haven't gathered yet, but on the other hand I haven't found a piece of article or question discussing this - which makes me doubt about such "wise knowledge" in the design.

What does the experts here have to say?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Hello again!
I accept this question to be a REPEATED question, whose answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

The term Functor was unknown to me and while trying to find an answer to my doubt (prior to this question's submission), I did not see any references to this term.

I still accept the answer from SergeyA, because his answer introduced me to the term and his explanation is answering my question. His answer -from my point of view- is extended by the answer found in the link I stated lines above.

Thanks!

Comment: So, you could pass an instance, of such class, to library functions, which accept functors as an argument (e.g. `std::sort`)?

Comment: Research term "functor"

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, nope, those are not opinions, but technical explanations of feasibility.

Comment: Callable objects are superior to standalone functions in at least two respects: better inlineability and ability to carry state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This technique mostly comes up with a generic programming and templates. The class which has `operator()` defined for it is called a `functor` and the beauty of such a class is that it could be used interchangeably with a function pointer in many cases. For example:

```
template<class F>
void call_f(F f) {
    f();
}
```

Will work with both functions and functors. Or, better example would be STL algorithms, such as `find_if`, `copy_if`, `remove_if`, etc. All of them have a template parameter which could be a function, a functor or (a case of a functor actually) a lambda.

The other benefit of such a class is that it's type defines it's objects. A function pointer is just a function pointer which always need to point to a specific function. But for stateless functors (ones which do not have any members) the type is enough to recreate the object as needed. This is how, for example, `std::less` is used for `std::map`. It doesn't take the actual object of the comparison, but it's type and creates the object from the type in-place.